# My own stopwatch in Android

Tags: android

I am developing a simple stopwatch the problem is  when the user presses the home button the thread witch calculates the time freezes how can i avoid that make the thread run in background ?

Comment: when the activity is in the background stop all the threads. all you need to calculate time is a start time! when the activity is back, use the starttime to calculate the value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A much simpler solution would be to record the start time of the stopWatch using system.currentTimeMillis.
when your activity onResume or onStart() is called, update the watch to show the time that elapsed from the time you've saved.

Comment: I have an app that has "stopwatch" functionality and this is exactly what I do. I recommend that you do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Service. Look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html